# How can I handle wildcards on the command line using Perl on Windows?

Tags: perl, windows-xp, file-globs

I though this would be simple, but apparently I can't do:

`script.pl *.ext`

in the WinXP command processor.

Is there a built-in solution? (i.e. not a CPAN module?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[File::DosGlob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/DosGlob.html) is a core module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::DosGlob qw( glob );
print map { "$_\n"} map { glob } @ARGV;
__END__
```

```
    C:\Temp> tgh *.pl
    ...
    tgh.pl
    tgm.pl
    thg.pl
    thk.pl
    tjl.pl
    tjm.pl
    tkj.pl
    tkl.pl
```

Comment: FWIW, File::Glob and built-in glob function are synonymous since Perl 5.6.

Comment: I meant File::DosGlob ... sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function.

> ...returns a (possibly empty) list of
>   filename expansions on the value of
>   EXPR such as the standard Unix shell
>   /bin/csh would do...

Comment: But *only* use it on Windows. If you use it on Unix, you risk globbing real file names; asterisks and question marks are valid characters in Unix file names.